# Exotic pop corn receipe

Tags: popcorn

I was wondering if there was an exotic pop corn receipe, something different that you find on theaters and circus. Does anyone know any receipe?

Comment: most theatres use oil/butter and salt.  Nothing too crazy.  Or you do mean candy popcorn?

Comment: I was looking for salty receipes

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=popcorn+exotic+recipe

Comment: I searched there before asking here and nothing.... Thank you for this incredible and usefull comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of making interesting popcorn is by getting some popcorn seasoning in bulk.  You can buy popcorn seasoning at a bulk food store, like cheddar, dill, ketchup, etc.

Trying to create your own flavor (needs to be dry) would be difficult.  [This site](http://www.howcrazycooks.com/2012/07/20/white-cheddar-popcorn/) suggests stealing some cheddar flavor from a mac and cheese box.

The basic method to making your own popcorn is described [here](http://www.whitelightsonwednesday.com/2011/10/kettle-corn/).  That recipe calls for sugar though, which might be worth a try on its own.

You could also use a BBQ rub with paprika, salt, garlic etc.

Most sites on the internet seem to be interested in making sweet popcorn, like s'more or caramel flavors.